# Error while performing angular Unit testing with SpyOn document

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I am trying to do the unit testing for component, I mocked the data and expecting some result but getting an error, below is my unit test.

```
it('should call getData method ', () => {
    const usageService = TestBed.get(UsageService);
    component.slug = 'slugName';
    spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue("slugName");
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(usageService.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

In above I am getting an error at line `spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue("slugName");`

Error is:

> Argument of type "slugName" is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'HTMLElement'.

This issue comes after upgrading jasmine version from **2.8** to **3.5.10**

I don't know what's wrong in this code, why previously it was working fine and now after upgrading it won't work.

please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: getElementById should return a HTML element.but your mock return a string. That doesn't make sense, it's why you have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a valid and self descriptive error, return type of getElementById is `HTMLElement` and you're returning `string`.

We would be in a better position to help you if you could paste the ngOnInit code which you're trying to test.

Nevertheless, you can take help from below code.

```
   it('should call getData method ', () => {
    const usageService = TestBed.get(UsageService);
    spyOn(usageService, 'getData'); // toHaveBeenCalled works on mocked method
    component.slug = 'slugName';
    const htmlEl = document.createElement('div'); // you can create the element which is there in your component.
    spyOn(document, 'getElementById').and.returnValue(htmlEl); // return created element on the previous line.
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(usageService.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to test in your code above? The slugName, or that a service has been called?

Either way, there are better ways of doing that.

### Testing if slugName has been set as id

Try using your fixture to get the html-object:

i.e, `componentFixture.debugElement.query('#slugName').nativeElement.id`

### Spy on your service to see if the "getData" component has been subscribed to.

`TestBed.inject(UsageService)`

I believe get is deprecated.